# Find the id of the button that called intent/activity? Android

Tags: android, button, android-activity, android-intent, bundle

My main activity layout contains 10 different buttons that all call the same activity (MapsActivity).

How can I find out the id of the button that was pressed from MapsActivity ? I tried to send it by using

> intent.putExtra("id", id);

But this id came out as the same when pushing any of the buttons.

Do I need to create a separate intent for each button that all call the same activity? Or can I use 1 intent and just change what value it passes to MapsActivity?

I hope I've explained this problem clearly enough! Thanks!

Comment: You use findViewById(...) to get the button right? The parameter you are passing to this function is button ID, isn't it?

Comment: yea i use findViewById(..) to get the button and set up its onClickListener which is where i create the intent

Comment: Are you using same listener for multiple buttons? If not, you can hardcode right?

Comment: Please show the code where you get the id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you say you add the listeners to the buttons in your code with findViewById, so i'm assuming you have requirements which mean that you can't design your layout in xml. so, when you set up your first activity, the  one that holds all these buttons, make sure they all get the same click listener. we can call this listener method `mapsButtonListener`. it should be declared like this:

```
public void mapsButtonListener(View sender) {
    int id = sender.getId();
    Intent mapsActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MapsActivity.class);
    mapsActivity.putExtra("button_id", id);
    startActivity(mapsActivity);
}
```

**about our button's id:s**

if you're placing your buttons with xml design, then just make sure they have id:s declared in the xml. however, if you're *not* using xml for these, but instead instantiating them in the code, then you'll have to use the method `setId(4)` to give your buttons id:s (don't give all of them 4 obviously, hehe). this should be done at the same time as adding the click listener. also, make sure you know what button gets what number, so that you can check this later.

**getting the id in MapsActivity**

once mapsActiviy starts, we'll want that id. we do this with the following line (inside the MapsActivity class):

```
 int id = getIntent().getIntExtra("button_id");
```